# all SharePoint sites are super slow - all of the sudden

Tags: site-collection

SharePoint 2013. 3 WFE, 2 App and 1 DB Server.

All of the sudden sites are super slow. What area should I look (beside logs)

Comment: Is a full crawl running? Check Database activity.

Comment: Does the logs show anything?

Comment: check the database server. we had the same problem a couple of months ago and the db server cpu was %100, had to failover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There too many reasons for this, you can check following things

- try to browse the sites directly bypassing the load balancer(using host file entry)
- check the cou and memory usage on the sharepoint server and database server
- check if there is any deadlock on db server
- look for throttling error in logs
- if you have antivirus installed on server check if that is blocking or slow down the things
- check ups logs for clue
- search crawls also cause the issue
- network connectivity also cause the issue
- check event logs
- check the status of database from central admin

Answer (score 0):

Other area you could validate to identify where the problem might be -

1.How is your Database server performing.

2. Is there a connectivity issue between the WFE's and the DB
3. If the performance problem are being reported by end users? Validating the site performance from the WFE's itself might be a quick test to eliminate the possibility of end user n/w issue.